# A series about a multiverse with a central nexus and lots of crossovers from other series

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to find this series. I remember it came up as a possible solution to a different Identification question on this Stack, but I can't find it now.

Edit:

It was a book, and it was pulp fiction style if memory serves.

Someone below suggested The Number of The Beast, and I believe that to be correct.

Comment: Please provide more details if possible. Such as media, time frame, and some key plot elements.

Comment: @Otis It may very well be, as it has turned out to be the same answer. But it was not the same question at all.

Comment: @DannyReagan: Not intended as a criticism, just linking together questions with the same answer for the benefit of future searchers.

Comment: @Otis A fair point, friend. My apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is very generic, the first work that comes to my mind are [heinlein's multiverse series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein#Series) some of the more dominant works with crossovers (including other authors) is [The Cat Who Walks Through Walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_Who_Walks_Through_Walls) & [The Number of the Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_(novel))

Comment: Generic though it might be, it seems to have been enough. Number of the Beast looks like the right book. Thanks!